# DBD::Oracle::st execute failed: system generated message

Tags: oracle

For oracle system generated **Software Error** messages during prepare/execute query invalid. displays complete query to user on a webpage. want to replace system generated message with user common message.

example:

Software error:

> DBD::Oracle::st execute failed: ORA-01722: invalid number (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 136 in 'SELECT EQUIPID, EQUIPSHORTNAME, MAXLIMITEDDAYS, STATUS, EQUIPNAME FROM LAB_EQUIPMENT_DETAILS WHERE CATEGORYID = '3' AND SUBCATEGORYID = <*>'   ' AND STATUS != 'DELETE'') [for Statement "SELECT EQUIPID, EQUIPSHORTNAME, MAXLIMITEDDAYS, STATUS, EQUIPNAME FROM LAB_EQUIPMENT_DETAILS WHERE CATEGORYID = '3' AND SUBCATEGORYID = '****' AND STATUS != 'DELETE'"] at /proj/aa/bb/Source/Global_Routines_general_apps.pm line 126.
>
> For help, please send mail to the webmaster ([...]), giving this error message and the time and date of the error.

Can anyone please help me in doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply wrap your execute statement in an eval block and catch the error.

```
eval {
$sth->execute();
...
};
if ( $@ ) {
# log the full error message
write_log( $sth->errstr );

# and re-throw the common message 
die 'HEY!!!! Something is messed up here!';
}
```